# Bar Buttons Not Showing Up - Swift

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

[image]

I ran my app and I'm having a hard time removing the back button (My `UITableViewController` has a **Navigation Controller** with a relationship to a `TabBar` Controller) and adding the bar button to my app. Here's what it looks like in the storyboard:

[image]

Code:

```
    class FeedTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }


    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return 0
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    }


    @IBAction func publishPhoto(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("publishPhotoOrVideo", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you are using push segue. If you dont want the back button to appear use replace segue.

Comment: In your storyboard select the segue that presents the tableVC, go to attribute inspector and there you can find dropdown list from there select Replace.

Comment: I see. I actually did that to fix the problem but it did not work. The TableVC has a relationship segue with a tab view controller btw.

Comment: @Tam, means you dont see `Public Photos` bar button. right ?

Comment: @None yes, I can't see it.

Comment: @Tam, have you bind BarButton object to its UIView in storyboard ?

Comment: Hi None, thanks for your help. Idk if it sounds obvious or not but isn't that just connecting it to your implementation file? I've been doing it on an off but it just seems like its something wrong with the storyboard settings as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically create the rightBar Button using following code. you need to add following code in `viewDidLoad` method.

```
 var refreshButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .Refresh, target: self, action: "buttonMethod") //Use a selector
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = refreshButton
```

Or if you have reference then you can directly assign as followed.

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = publicPhotoButton
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: Neither help unfortunately. I think it's an issue with the view controller itself, since neither the bar buttons nor the navigation title show up. Is there a way to make sure the code in from the implementation file shows up besides the usual way of assigning it in the storyboard?

Comment: @Tam, you can present controller instead of push controller. which is consider your implementation Navigation bar from storyboard.

Comment: I tried to, but if I do I have to remove the relationship to the tab bar controller then. I think the problem may be linked to the back button? I've written code to hide it and it doesn't show up either.

Comment: which code you have written to hide back button? can you please post that .

Comment: Usually self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated:true); I've actually tried several different ones, but none of them worked.

Comment: @Tam, actually i was face difficulty to produce this bugs. can you please upload sample code if you have not any issue. so i will look over it

Comment: Hi None, sorry for the long time between responses. If you're still willing to look at my work I will send you the link.

Comment: Okay give me your link

Comment: @Tam, actually some files are missing from source code.. i am not able to run your project. do some needful

Comment: Sorry. Let me fix it and send the link back to you.